# Equivalent to django Form to show object contents

Tags: python, django

Is there any Django class used to show the contents of an object model in a non-modifiable way? Something like this for forms to edit the objects from a model:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Test
```

using it as:

```
def generic_view(request):
    form = TestForm()
    return render_to_response('generic/generic_view.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

and then in the template:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

but showing just the contents of an object instead of a form?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `repr()` against the model instance will get you a (admittedly ugly) representation of the instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the source of [Databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/) to see how it does it. It introspects models and displays the data of objects with minimal configuration, so it probably has a component that does what you want.